# Gyroscope on Moto 360

Tags: wear-os

Is anyone using the gyroscope on Moto 360? The values are quite strange. Whew I twisted my wrist, I got peak values like 100 rad/s; while on Samsung Gear Live, I only got values around 8 rad/s. Is this some kind of calibration issue?

and according to the information provided by Sensor.toString() on Moto 360, the maximun value is 34.9
{Sensor name="Gyro Sensor", vendor="Motorola", version=1, type=4, maxRange=34.9, resolution=0.01, power=0.45, minDelay=40000}

I even got values like below when I put it on the desk.

```html
10-02 17:16:55.054    7354-7354/ D/gyro﹕ -18.242777 8.1562507E-4 2.7187503E-4
10-02 17:16:55.775    7354-7354/ D/gyro﹕ -18.242777 8.1562507E-4 -0.0040781256
```

code to register gyro:

```html
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mGyroscopeSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscopeSensor, 40000);
...

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        Log.d("gyro", event.timestamp + "\t" + event.values[0] + "\t" + event.values[1] + "\t" + event.values[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to register for the gyroscope values, and so forth?

Comment: please see the code snippet in my original post